# Система лайков (рейтингов)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть веб приложение на asp.net mvc. Приложение идет как социальный сеть. Я хочу тута добавить функциональност чтобы юзер мог ставить лайки и дислайки как в вк. Я сделал c помощью `Ajax.ActionLink`. Но он чета долго работает когда ставиш лайки.Как можно это оптимизировать или есть уже готовые решение

Вот мой код на View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "GetPostLikes", "Post", new { id = item.PostID, isLike = true },
     new AjaxOptions 
         { 
            UpdateTargetId = "postLike_" + item.PostID, 
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
         },
     new { @class = "fa fa-thumbs-up text-success" })

     @*<a class="@cl_Like" style="padding-left:10px;cursor:pointer;"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up">&nbsp;</i></a>*@

  <span id="postLike_@item.PostID">
     @Html.Action("GetPostLikes", "Post", new { id = item.PostID })
  </span>
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "GetPostLikes", "Post", new { id = item.PostID, isLike = false },
     new AjaxOptions 
         { 
            UpdateTargetId = "postLike_" + item.PostID, 
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
         },
     new { @class = "fa fa-thumbs-down text-danger" })
```

Обработчик на контроллере:

```
public PartialViewResult Like(int id)
{
    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var post = db.UserLikes.Where(m => m.PostID == id);
    var result = new PostLikesCountModel();
    if (post != null)
    {
        result.like = post.Where(m => m.UserID == userID && m.user_like).Count();
        result.dislike = post.Where(m => m.UserID == userID && m.user_dislike).Count();
    }
    else
    {
        result.like = 0;
        result.dislike = 0;
    }
    return PartialView(result);
}
```

Comment: Что подразумевается под "долго работает когда ставиш лайки" ? Только в этом проблема ?

Comment: Посмотрите в браузере через F12 что именно долго отрабатывает - серверная часть или клиентская.